# How to send search text to findInPage in Electron

Tags: electron

I try using [contents.findInPage](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentsfindinpagetext-options).
I have code in index.js:

```
  const { webContents } = require('electron')
  webContents.on('found-in-page', (event, result) => {
    if (result.finalUpdate) webContents.stopFindInPage('clearSelection')
  })

  const requestId = webContents.findInPage('api')
  console.log(requestId)
```

And code in component:

```
searchText(value){
    this.query = value;
    if (this.query.length > 0) {
        ipcRenderer.send('api', this.query);
    }
}
```

I wrote this code on the example of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40987432/6678345).
But function find not work. I do not understand how I can send the text to be searched and the word to be searched.

**How I can use function findInPage ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sorry my answer to the other question wasn't clear enough (it was 2 years ago! I don't remember it that well but I'll give it a shot)

This is the documentation for [webcontents](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents) and [IPCMain](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main)

Here's what I have in my main.development.js (globals for the mainWindow and ipc communication):

```
mainWindow.on('focus', () => {
globalShortcut.register('CmdorCtrl+F', () => {
  mainWindow.webContents.send('find_request', '');
  });
});

mainWindow.webContents.on('found-in-page', (event, result) => {
if (result.finalUpdate) {
  mainWindow.webContents.stopFindInPage('keepSelection');
}
});
ipcMain.on('search-text', (event, arg) => {
  mainWindow.webContents.findInPage(arg);
});

mainWindow.on('blur', () => {
   globalShortcut.unregister('CmdorCtrl+F');
});
```

Then I made an ipc listener for CmdorCtrl+F:

```
ipcRenderer.on('find_request', () => {
  const modalbox = document.getElementById('modalbox');
 if (modalbox.style.display === 'block') {
   modalbox.style.display = 'none';
} else {
  modalbox.style.display = 'block';
 }
});
```

Then I made a modal searchbox:

```
const searchBox = (
  <div
    id="modalbox"
    style={{ display: 'none', position: 'fixed', zIndex: 1 }}
  ><input type="text" onChange={Calls.searchPage} />
  </div>);
```

The onchange sends the input text to the ipc listener:

```
static searchPage(event) {
  ipcRenderer.send('search-text', event.target.value);
}
```

I hope this is enough for you to get it fixed :)

Comment: Your answer wery help mi, thanks ;) But I have second problem. In my application I have menu in top application (it' scomponent `Menu.vue`). And when I search somethink word (in `News.vue` component), electron also marks words that are on the menu. Do you know how to fix it ?

Comment: Well, there are two ways, you can give up on webcontents.findinpage and write your own (not recommended). Or, you can put the menu in a separate webview as per this discussion:
https://discuss.atom.io/t/using-webcontents-findinpage-to-implement-typical-find-function/25309

Comment: This answer helped me a lot!  I also have a new problem though - how about doing a findNext? Want to be able to navigate to next matching text by pressing 'Enter' key or 'Next' button.. Thanks

Comment: Yep, same question, findNext not works properly: focus not moving after first founded result, did anyone solve it?