# How to perform window search in Node.JS Electron app, similar to a Ctrl+F in browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, electron

I am trying to find a way to perform window search on my Node JS Electron app that will search through the contents of the present Electron window simulating the Ctrl+F function of a web browser.
I haven't been able to find a satisfactory solution to my problem yet.

---

I have looked at this answer:

[How to send search text to findInPage in Electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57100685/how-to-send-search-text-to-findinpage-in-electron)

...but since I am new to Electron, I am finding it difficult to implement this for myself.

Comment: Where do you want to perform the search exactly?

Comment: Where would this be implemented? A code editor plugin? Your own app?

Comment: My own app, basically an HTML page.

Comment: How do you display a html page in node.js? Is there a browser or not?

Comment: No browser, just the node js app @Bergi

Comment: Are you possibly referring to an electron app? node.js runs from the terminal. It's just the v8 JavaScript engine from chromium, and in itself doesn't have any html rendering engine.

Comment: Yep, Electron app @David784

Comment: @AakashSinghBais An electron app *is* a browser

Comment: I am new to it sorry, and thanks for correcting @Bergi

Comment: Looks like Electron's `webContents` has a [findInPage](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentsfindinpagetext-options) method. Google searched for `electron findinpage example` and found what appears to be a [minimal sample project](https://github.com/edulan/electron-search-example). Might check it out and see if that can do what you want.